# iphone location without using coreLocation framework

Tags: ios4

I need to get iphone location wihout using coreLocation Framework. Is there any solution for this.

waiting for your repy...!

thanks in adv.

Comment: What's the reason for not using CoreLocation ?

Comment: thnks for reply.........no reason dude..! i jst want to knw is there any way for it or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using private APIs and a *lot* of effort: yes. In practice: no.

Comment: Were you able to implement it?? If yes, can please give more idea on proceeding towards achieving the same.

Comment: I did not even try as there is no point in trying: just use CoreLocation.